# Is there an algorithm to find the number of digits in 2^n, where n is a positive integer?

Tags: number-theory

Is there an algorithm to find the number of digits in 2^2030 ?

$2^1=2$

$2^2=4$

$2^3=8$

$2^4=16$

$2^5=32$

$2^6=64$

$2^7=128$

...

$2^{10}=1024$

Answer (score 5):

The number of digits in $2^n$ is $1+floor(n \log_{10} 2)$.

Using $\log_{10} 2 \approx 0.30103$ gives you 612 digits.

Here is an explanation:

A number $x$ has $k$ digits in base 10 iff $10^{k-1} \le x < 10^k$. Taking logs, we get $k-1 \le  \log_{10} x < k$, which means that $floor(\log_{10} x)=k-1$. So, $k=1+floor(\log_{10} x)$.

An answer to the question in the title needs high-precision approximations of $\log_{10} 2$.

Comment: Care to explain why is this the case?

Comment: @JohnWO, see my edited answer.

Comment: See also http://oeis.org/A129344 and try to find a pattern.

Comment: You can use \lfloor and \rfloor to get the $\lfloor$ and $\rfloor$ symbols.

Comment: @PeterPhipps, I know. I was lazy and also not sure the OP would understand the notation.

Comment: @lhf Your value for $\log_{10}2$ is off, it should be $0.30103$, accurate to 8 decimal places.

Comment: @ErickWong, fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, let's suppose you don't have access to floating-point computations, but you can compute with rational numbers.
We have the series (for $|x|<1$)
$$ \ln \left( \frac{1+x}{1-x}\right) = 2 x + \frac{2}{3} x^3 + \frac{2}{5} x^5 + \frac{2}{7} x^7 + \ldots$$
and in particular, if $0 < x < 1$,
$$  2 x + \frac{2}{3} x^3 + \frac{2}{5} x^5 + \frac{2}{7} x^7 
< \ln\left( \frac{1+x}{1-x}\right) < 2 x + \frac{2}{3} x^3 + \frac{2}{5} x^5 +  
\frac{2 x^7}{7(1 - x^2)}$$
For $x = 1/3$ this gives us
$$ \dfrac{53056}{76545} < \ln(2) < \dfrac{23581}{34020}$$
while for $x = 1/9$ we have
$$ {\frac {37355104}{167403915}} < \ln  \left( 5/4 \right) < {\frac {
3689393}{16533720}}
$$
Then $2030 \log_{10}(2) = \dfrac{2030 \ln 2}{\ln(5/4) + 3 \ln(2)}$ is between
$\dfrac{23263994880}{38070491}$ and $\dfrac{94221399069}{154182208}$, both of which are between $611$ and $612$.
So, $612$ digits.